# Change row values in specific pandas data frame column with python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Following problem.

I have a data frame with the following format.

```
   Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4  
1    0    0    0    0
2    0    0    0    0
```

Furthermore, I have a List of values that match the column names:

```
ColNameList1 = [Col1, Col3] #list for the first row
ColNameList2 = [Col3, Col4] #list for the second row
```

The target is to change the value of 0 to 1 for every column row match.

```
    Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4  
1    1    0    1    0 
2    0    0    1    1
```

I did some intense research on the Pandas documentation and also google and stack overflow but it seems there is not a fitting solution for this problem.

As always any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can simply use loc and set values:

```
df.loc[1,ColNameList1]=1

df.loc[2,ColNameList2]=1

df
Out[10]: 
   Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4
1     1     0     1     0
2     0     0     1     1
```

Comment: thanks for the prompt reply, I got the error AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'loc'. Do I miss something?

Comment: That's strange. Is your df actually a pandas dataframe? Can you show the complete error stack trace?. Can you also do a df.head()?

Comment: you should check the data type of your data frame it seems to be some problem.

Comment: pandas version 0.19.2
`df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Col1'] = [0, 0]
df['Col2'] = [0, 0]
df['Col3'] = [0, 0]
df['Col4'] = [0, 0]

print df 
print type(df)
ColNameList1 = ['Col1', 'Col3'] #list for the first row
ColNameList2 = ['Col3', 'Col4'] #list for the second row
df = df.loc[1,ColNameList2]=1

print df`

when I run this code i get

`   Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4
0     0     0     0     0
1     0     0     0     0
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'loc' 
`

Comment: 2 problems: a:) You can't do df = df.loc[1,ColNameList2]=1, just do df.loc[1,ColNameList2]=1. b:) In your example data, the df index is 1 based here it appears to be 0 based. If it's 0 based, you need to use df.loc[0] and df.loc[1] respectively.